# Python / Selenium / PhantomJS: "Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver."

Tags: python

I'm trying to get Selenium to use phantomjs on a Windows machine. My code compiles without any error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import cookielib
import re
from splinter import Browser

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:/Program Files (x86)/phantomjs-1.9.2-windows')
```

But every single time I run it I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/~PROJECT/disinfo/py/bs.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:/Program Files (x86)/phantomjs-1.9.2-windows')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py", line 63, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.", e)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

I've been getting this error for hours. "Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver". The simplest examples online show installing selenium with PIP and then phantomjs with NodeJS NPM, which is how I did it. Selenium's location is in my PYTHONPATH as well. I frankly have no idea what the hell this thing wants from me. Any ideas?

Comment: Same issues on basic code that once worked, thought I had broke my python structure at first.

Comment: Welp, it looks like phantomjs' dev has admitted that the python bindings are behind. https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/236 So much for using phantomjs. Wish I would've known that before I spent several ****ing hours trying to wrangle phantomjs to life.

Comment: Same feelings here. Why it is so important to learn code and not libraries unless they are maintained by a large community. You can never expect one guy to maintain his project especially if not making any money off of the hard work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. I needed to provide the full path to the exe, as described in the [documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_phantomjs/selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\phantomjs-1.9.2\phantomjs.exe')
```

Comment: This did indeed allow it to dial out, hooray. Now the only problem is, every element I try to print, it just gives me a "selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver.WebDriver object at 0x0000000002F54668" or a unicode ID. I recommend lorien's Grab instead. https://bitbucket.org/lorien/grab/src/98cbbfa4d2d2a5d4207c1086e24b4b922380bbfc/grab/tools/russian.py?at=default

Comment: true story!!  wish I could upvote 5 times.

Comment: Didn't work for me... I had to edit service.py as per DT_Lvhyy's answer.

Comment: It looks like for Ubuntu and Linux systems, ~ should be the actual path from root to the directory

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify `...\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py`

This [google code page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=977c310569539f00c4090db244276e224d9884b3) would help.